Install dotnet-sdk-8.0 on Ubuntu 24.04
Has anyone been able to install the dotnet-sdk-8.0 package on Noble Numbat?
$ sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-8.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-runtime-deps-8.0 : Depends: libicu but it is not installable or
                                    libicu72 but it is not installable or
                                    libicu71 but it is not installable or
                                    libicu70 but it is not installable or
                                    libicu69 but it is not installable or
                                    libicu68 but it is not installable or
                                    libicu67 but it is not installable or
                                    libicu66 but it is not installable or
                                    libicu65 but it is not installable or
                                    libicu63 but it is not installable or
                                    libicu60 but it is not installable or
                                    libicu57 but it is not installable or
                                    libicu55 but it is not installable or
                                    libicu52 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

The package libicu74 is installed Is this an early bug to wait to be resolved?

This will require Microsoft to update the dependencies.  Their packaging does not accept libicu74 in its dependencies, as evidenced in the messaging.  Note that since 24.04 only JUST released, Microsoft will be much slower to adapt their repositories and dependencies to Noble.

I suspected so much, but I was wondering if others had the same issue, or if this was only on my system. 24.04 is listed as a supported version, so I found this unexpected.

Are you using the Microsoft feeds or the Canonical-provided distro feeds? For 24.04 and onwards Microsoft will no longer be providing .NET packages, instead Canonical's dotnet packages will be used. You can see a post about this here. This means if there are packaging issues they should be solvable entirely by Canonical (of course with upstream fixes where required, etc).

Yes you're right! I disabled the MS repo and the package installed successfully from the Canonical repo.It appears to be fully up to date too! Thanks!

I got solution :

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dotnet/backports

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#register-the-ubuntu-net-backports-package-repository

sudo apt-get update && 
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0

solution source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu-install?tabs=dotnet6&pivots=os-linux-ubuntu-2404
worked for me on new install of ubuntu server 24.04
all ok.
